# Why Lambda Baryon and Sigma Baryon unequal sum isospin with "really" isospin?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, isospin-symmetry

For information isospin for $u$-quark = 1/2, isospin for $d$-quark = -1/2 and isospin for $s$-quark = 0.

Lambda Baryon consists $uds$ quarks,therefore sum isospin 1/2-1/2+0=0, It true.
But sum isospin for Sigma Baryon consists $uds$ quarks  too isospin equal to 0 ,but data written isospin for it the particle = 1...A contradiction has come...

The electric charge is therefore equal to by isospin and hypercharge.

$Q=I+(1/2)Y$

$Y=B+S$

Y for Sigma zero and Lambda = 0 ,

Q for Sigma zero = 1+1/2 * 0 = 1, Q for Lambda = 0+1/2 * 0 = 0. Sigma has a charge, Lambda is neutral in charge. But the fact is that they are both neutral in charge.

They have the same spin, charge and ALMOST the same mass, even the same quark composition. They behave the same in interactions. But what is more different from each other, only isospin?

"WHAT'S THE HORROR GOING ON HERE?" - the famous quote from the film here is  to describe this situation.

Comment: Red alert: The Gell-Mann--Nishijima formula you wrote is wrong! It should be $Q=I_3+Y/2$ ... *I* is reserved for $\vec I \cdot \vec I= I(I+1) ~1\!\! 1$...

Answer (score 2):

“Isospin,” short for “isotopic spin,” is a symmetry of the strong interaction in the limit where electric charge is not important. Of course electric charge never goes away completely, but the strong interaction is so much stronger than electromagnetism that sometimes electric charge can be ignored.

In this limit, the neutron and the proton are two “charge states” of the same “particle,” the nucleon. The “spin” part of the name arises because transitions between the two charge states have rules very much like the rules for rotating a two-state spinor between “up” and “down.” Furthermore the rules for combining multiple nucleons into nuclei are closely related to the rules for combining multiple angular momenta.

In a system with angular momentum quantum number $L$, you have $2L+1$ “projections” of that angular momentum onto whichever axis quantizes your system. If your system has spherical symmetry, all of those projections are indistinguishable, and the only way to deduce the existence of the degenerate states is by doing statistics. But if the spherical symmetry is broken, the different projections may have different energies. For example, a magnetic field establishes a preferred direction in space, and separates spin multiplets in a way first described by Zeeman.

In a system with isospin $I$, you have $2I+1$ “projections” of that isospin onto the different available charge states. When we say that the lambda is an isosinglet ($I=0$) and that the sigma is an isotriplet ($I=1$), we mean that, of the four lightest strange baryons, three with with charge states $(+,0,-)$ have approximately the same mass, while the fourth baryon has zero charge and a mass that is some ways off.

Note especially that there are *three* charge states in the sigma isospin triplet, just like there are three charge states in the pion isotriplet.

An amusing homework problem is to try and predict the branching ratios for $\Lambda\to p\pi^-$ versus $\Lambda\to n\pi^+$ by assuming the final state, in the charge-blind strong interaction, has $I=\frac12$. You’ll want your Clebsch-Gordan table.

Comment: Thanks! I need to think about it, I'm just a guy from the Internet who wants to understand particle physics and quantum mechanics, when I saw the table in the "homework", my eyes and forehead soon got even more literally than a metaphor...It sounds and looks intimidating, but why

Comment: I need it is not clear and one horror. It seems to me that Sigma, one in isospin, is purely a formalism to distinguish them from Lymbda, their each other. If the charge can be neglected with isospin, does this mean that the charge formula for isospin and hypercharge is incorrect? Isospin projection i.e. I3 is 2I+1 then is it true? Why then there are two zeros in charge and hence four baryons which is one of them Lambda, but Sigma isospin 1, with the same composition. I think even more questions have appeared.

Comment: It 's all a single comment .divided into two parts

Comment: Oh, I see where you are coming from now. The similarities between the rules of light-quark flavor dynamics and the rules of angular momentum are much less helpful to people who haven’t studied the rules of quantum-mechanical angular momentum. That usually takes about half of an intro-quantum semester to do properly. Briefly, …

Comment: The charge projection quantum number $I_3$ obeys $|I_3|\leq I$, and is therefore always different from $2I+1$. The combination of two doublets into a symmetric singlet and an antisymmetric triplet is a nifty trick that I can’t explain in a comment. You might try to get some real-time back-and-forth in [chat].